# Why doesn't "xattr -w com.apple.FinderInfo /opt" work?

Tags: macos, finder, file-attributes, macos-highsierra

I'm trying to add the `com.apple.FinderInfo` extended attribute to my /opt directory so that it will show up as an installable folder for installing packages on MacOS 10.13.2 High Sierra.  I tried running this command:

```
sudo xattr -w com.apple.FinderInfo /opt
```

then run:

```
xattr /opt
```

I get:

```
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
```

but on other folders which have the attribute, they show:

```
com.apple.FinderInfo
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to supply the value to assign to the `com.apple.FinderInfo` attribute (probably in hex, since it usually contains nonprintable/null characters). Something like `sudo xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo SomeHexDataGoesHere /opt`. What Finder info are you trying to set?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was just trying to get `/opt` to show up as an option when I install packages.  The only difference I could find from Library, System, Applications, and Users folder is that they have extended metadata, having `com.apple.FinderInfo` set. So, I ended up doing `sudo xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "\`xattr -px com.apple.FinderInfo /scratch\`" /opt`, which set the metadata correctly, but unfortunately still didn't solve my hidden `/opt` folder problem.  Found the example here: https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html